What is the purposes of a novel scene?
I wonder if it’s the way I’m phrasing it, but struggling to find an answer.
What are the purpose/purposes of a scene? Or maybe job is a better way of describing it?
For example, scenes should reveal new information to the reader as one of them.
Hopefully that makes sense!

Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_(performing_arts)

Scenes exist to change the story as told so far. Obviously that includes the very first scene -- The story so far doesn't exist, so we need to introduce a character, usually the hero, existing in their normal world. (Sometimes this can be a place, or point in history, but usually it is a character).
Changing the story doesn't just mean changing the plot, a scene could be to change the reader's perception of what is happening, or what the character is, etc.
If I introduce a character, Carmichael, and everybody loves Carmichael, he's happy, he's joking as he walks down the street, I am changing the reader's perception of Carmichael from "generic guy" to popular, funny, friendly guy.
But I (the author) may be doing that on purpose for some shock value; and in the next scene Carmichael, chuckling at joke he heard, pulls on a mask and robs a store at gunpoint. Changing the reader's perception of Carmichael.
There is no other purpose for a scene to exist, they change the reader's perception of what is going on. Multiple scenes in a row (even two) that do not change the reader's perception are boring -- okay, we've got it already, the crew is lost!
What happens next, after they are lost? Which member of the crew discovers something that will get them un-lost? What were they doing?
When writers belabor the same point scene after scene, readers start skimming ahead for the change.
You avoid them putting down the story by ensuring every scene changes their perception of the characters, the situation, the enemy, the mystery, or the reader's understanding of what is going on.
In the broad sense, this is the only purpose of the scene -- to change something about the story so far. That includes "all that kind of stuff":

Develop characters -- change the reader's perception of the characters.
Reveal new knowledge -- change the reader's perception of the puzzle.
Reveal false knowledge -- change the reader's perception (for the worse) of the problem.
Make the space feel real -- change the reader's perception of the setting.
Establish the stakes -- change the reader's perception of the consequences of failure.
Reveal feelings -- change the reader's perception of a character.

And so on. If the scene doesn't change anything, it should be cut. For example, despite the "show don't tell" maxim, we don't illustrate that a character is living a boring life by actually boring the reader with scene after scene of a boring life. One "iconic" scene or montage of a boring life is enough, then we need to introduce a non-boring element or we will lose the reader.
When you write a story, you are selecting the points in the story, the scenes, where the reader's perception is changed from "A" to "B", then "B to C", and finally "Y to Z". (Not to imply there are only 25 scenes, but you get the idea.)
This is especially true in movies; which have to be pretty tight. Watch a good movie, make note of the scene changes, and try to figure out what was changed about the story, in your mind, by that scene. What new information was imparted, that you did not know before the scene began?
In a good movie this can be visual, auditory, or musical -- the music intentionally reflects the emotions of the character.

Scene is an overloaded word in writing -- it can be used to mean different things. From your example, I think your asking about the use of scene as a method the author uses to encapsulate a moment of their story in a specific location at a specific time. In this context, a scene is like a sub-chapter. Or, to put it another way, a chapter is made up of one or more scenes.
For instance, a chapter might follow four people around as they meet and talk to each other over breakfast over a few days. In this contrived example, the fist scene might be their first breakfast, and the second scene might be 2nd or the 3rd. How many scenes a chapter has is up to the author. As is the length.
In published novels (and short stories), the end of a scene is annotated by either an extra blank line after a paragraph (and sometimes by a dinkus).
Take a look at most any novel and you'll see the scene breaks.
In a manuscript, in standard manuscript format, a scene break is annotated by a dinkus or a pound sign (#). Authors submit their work to publishers in manuscript format
Other means of the word scene as it pertains to writing are to differentiate between writing that summarizes what is happening in a story and what is shown in real time. Scene v. Summary. Another meaning is as a synonym for setting -- as in the descriptive details of the room or the battle field or spaceship were the scene (1st meaning) of the story is being told.
That said, all writing should move a story forward, or develop the characters, or  make the space feel real, or establish the stakes, and all that kind of stuff. A scene is an encapsulation of a moment of a story that makes up a chapter.

Thank you for the detailed answer but I think my question is for the last part in particular: That said, all writing should move a story forward, or develop the characters, or make the space feel real, or establish the stakes, and all that kind of stuff.
What other reasons would there be for a scene to exist? What purposes are there for scenes to exist?
Apologies, I know my wording is likely where I’m confusing things!
